# How much logic make sense in a razor view in Asp.Net Mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm currently asking myself if I'm using too much logic in my razor view.

I learned to separate logic and markup, but razor gives us nice opportunities to work with. I really like the opportunity to give  "dynamic" css classes like in my following example.

I'm sure what I've done is not a best practice but how would it be done correctly?

```html
@using AtheleteManager.Helpers
@using AtheleteManager.Models
@using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities
@model AtheleteManager.Models.Athlete

<div class="container col-lg-9 col-md-9 hidden-sm hidden-xs panel panel-primary topten padding-leftright-thirty">
   <div class="panel-heading negative-margin-leftright-thirty">
      <h1 id="">Timeline</h1>
   </div>
   <div id="timeline">
      <div class="row timeline-movement timeline-movement-top">
         <div class="timeline-badge timeline-future-movement">
            <a href="#">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row timeline-movement">

         @foreach (var trainingPost in Model.TrainingPosts)
         {
            string className;
            string offSet;
            string debitsOrCredits;
            var dateHelper = new DateHelper();
            <div class="timeline-badge">
               <span class="timeline-balloon-date-day">@trainingPost.Date.Day</span><br />
               <span class="timeline-balloon-date-month">@dateHelper.ToShortMonthName(trainingPost.Date)</span>
            </div>
            if (trainingPost.Id % 2 != 0)
            {
               className = "col-sm-6 timeline-item";
               offSet = "col-sm-11";
               debitsOrCredits = "credits";
            }
            else
            {
               className = "col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-6 timeline-item";
               offSet = "col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11";
               debitsOrCredits = "debits";
            }
            foreach (var executedWorkouts in trainingPost.ExecutedWorkouts)
            {
               <div class="@className">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="@offSet">
                        <div class="timeline-panel @debitsOrCredits">
                           <ul class="timeline-panel-ul">
                              <li>
                                 <p>
                                    <small class="text-muted"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> @trainingPost.Date.ToShortDateString()</small>
                                 </p>
                              </li>
                              <li><span class="importo">Workout</span></li>
                              <li>
                                 <h3>@executedWorkouts.Workout.Name</h3>
                              </li>
                              <li><span class="causale">      <b>@executedWorkouts.Workout.Rounds</b></span> </li>
                           </ul>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            }
         }
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *personally* do not like placing too much business logic inside View.

The main reason is ***it is not easy to Unit Test a view*** compare to an action method. You either have to use ***Razor Generator*** or implement ***Integration Tests***. Either way requires a lot of initial setup, and they tend to break easily.

So, I'll make those as properties inside TrainingPost class, and set those values inside Controller. Then when you write Unit Tests, you can assert those values.

```
public class TrainingPost 
{
   ...
   public string ClassName { get; set; }
   public string OffSet { get; set; }
   public string DebitsOrCredits { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as the logic you are putting in your markup is view-related you are good.

Personally I don't like blocks of `C#` code inside my views therefore I would replace your if statements with the conditional operator.

Something like this:

```
<div class="@(trainingPost.Id % 2 != 0 ? "col-sm-11" : "col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11")">
```

This will help to keep you view more concise and more readable.

Finally consider that as many IT related questions, I don't think there is a correct answer, but just different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

It is the best way what you do. 
Also, i do same in order to use as possible as i can the advantages of Razor.

Views are updated only when Model is updated.

You can enhance that with making css files in BundelConfig